# java loop will not end

Tags: java, loops

I am having trouble on a program and I can't seem to fix the problem. I have a team roster program that gives the option of replacing a player's number and rating, but when that option is used the loop keeps going and it won't end and go back to the menu for the other options. If anyone could help point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PlayerRoster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] playerJerseyNumber = new int[5];
            int[] playerRating = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                //Taking jersey number till it is in the range of 0-99
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1)
                            + "'s jersey number:");
                    playerJerseyNumber[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (0 <= playerJerseyNumber[i] && playerJerseyNumber[i] <= 99) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Jersey number must be 0-99");
                    }
                }
                //Taking playerRating till it is in the range of 1-9
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Enter player " + (i + 1) + "'s rating:");
                    playerRating[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (1 <= playerRating[i] && playerRating[i] <= 9) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Player's ratings must be 1-9");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("ROSTER");
            //Displaying the rosters
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " -- Jersey number: "
                        + playerJerseyNumber[i] + ", Rating: "
                        + playerRating[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            //Printing the menu
            do {
                System.out.println("MENU " + "u - Update player rating");
                System.out.println("a - Output players above a rating");
                System.out.println("r - Replace player");
                System.out.println("o - Output roster");
                System.out.println("q - Quit");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Choose an option:");
                char choice = scanner.next().charAt(0);
                switch (choice) {
                    case 'u': {
                        System.out.println("Enter a jersey number:");
                        int playerJersey = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter a new rating for player:");
                        int newRating = scanner.nextInt();
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            if (playerJerseyNumber[i] == playerJersey) {
                                playerRating[i] = newRating;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'a': {
                        System.out.println("Enter a rating:");
                        int aboveRating = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("ABOVE " + aboveRating);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            if (playerRating[i] > aboveRating) {
                                System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1)
                                        + " -- Jersey number: "
                                        + playerJerseyNumber[i] + ", Rating: "
                                        + playerRating[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'r': {
                        boolean flag = true;
                        do {
                            System.out.println("Enter a jersey number:");
                            int newRating, playerNewJersey;
                            int playerJersey = scanner.nextInt();
                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                                if ((playerJerseyNumber[i] == playerJersey)) {
                                    //Taking jersey number till it is in the range of 0-99
                                    while (true) {
                                        System.out.println("Enter a new jersey number:");
                                        playerNewJersey = scanner.nextInt();
                                        if (0 <= playerNewJersey && playerNewJersey <= 99) {
                                            break;
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Jersey number must be 0-99");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //Taking playerRating till it is in the range of 1-9
                                    while (true) {
                                        System.out.println("Enter a new rating for player:");
                                        newRating = scanner.nextInt();
                                        if (1 <= newRating && newRating <= 9) {
                                            break;
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Player's ratings must be 1-9");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    playerJerseyNumber[i] = playerNewJersey;
                                    playerJerseyNumber[i] = playerJersey;
                                    playerRating[i] = newRating;
                                    flag = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!flag) {
                                System.out.println("Error: Invalid Jersey Number... Try Again...");
                            }
                        } while (flag);
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'o': {
                        System.out.println("ROSTER");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1)
                                    + " -- Jersey number: " + playerJerseyNumber[i]
                                    + ", Rating: " + playerRating[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case 'q':
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                if (choice == 'q') break;
            } while (true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (flag) {
    System.out.println("Error: Invalid Jersey Number... Try Again...");
}                        }
```

Removing the ! solves the problem. Also, a few lines above it there is

```
playerJerseyNumber[i] = playerNewJersey;
playerJerseyNumber[i] = playerJersey;
```

I don't understand why you need to reassign it to playerJersey. This would cause the jersey number to not get updated.

Comment: When i try to replace a jersey number/rating for a player, It changes it but I am not sure how to get it to go back to the menu after changing a single players information, it just keeps asking which player to change.

Comment: It seems to work fine with the changes I suggested. You can try it out here(https://repl.it/repls/ConfusedSereneConsulting) and see if what you say still happens.